# Not understanding this Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

In [this example of Django project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views), and in the templates section (book_detail.html), I do not understand this code:

```
book.genre.all|join:", "
```

"book.genre.all" are List of all objects from the Genre class that are connected to the book object (from Book class) by a ManyToMany key.

Why are pipe characters being used to join or split these objects? Why not use `", ".join(book.genre.all)`?

Comment: The template language is different from Python syntax and doesn't understand `",".join(book.genre.all)`

Comment: It is not python scrypt it is django template language https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/

Comment: Django template language does not support calling functions etc. That pipe as you call it indicates a `filter` which we are using check [built-in filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference)

Answer (score 0):

They called as template filters in django. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) for custom filter also [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#join) for built-in join filter.